# VPN protocol suitable for connections with poor reliability

Tags: networking, vpn

I need to set up a VPN that allows users to connect while in the field, often via connections that involve high latency and loads of packetloss (usually via 3G, CDMA, or whatever is available). Up until now I've mostly dealt with [vpnc](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vpnc), and while good under ideal circumstances, it is simply not suitable for use in my scenario:

What I need is a protocol that is:

- Relatively fast to connect/reconnect
- Low bandwidth overhead
- Fault tolerant. If a packet is lost, forget about it and move on. Error correction and/or recovery is handled well on the application level anyway.
- Free, preferably open source
- able to run on linux, both clientside and serverside

Are there any VPN protocols especially suitable for poor reliability connections such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net) should be fine.

Comment: It's gonna be a while before I can run proper tests, but I'll give that a go, cheers!

Comment: @Jarmund: good luck!